# Sitecore Cortex Content Tagging API feature

Tags: sxa, cortex

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1.

I followed the steps in the following [Link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-the-sitecore-cortex-content-tagging-framework-in-your-custom-solution.html) to trigger content tagging,

[image]

And the output wasn't as expected.

1] The item has been tagged but the tags appear to be corrupted or unavailable.

2] Also, when I tag a few different items, they all get the same unavailable IDs.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong or how to fix this?

3] The tags also appear in the semantics field not in the tags field, how to make them appear in the Tags field instead of semantics?

[image]

Comment: For SXA it is different see https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/integrating-sxa-with-sitecore-cortex--content-tagging.html

Comment: @JanBluemink I want to do it without SXA. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: For me it works. are there any tags stored in /Data/Tags coming from the Cortex tagging?. for example the Music tag e.t.c also the tags should be storage in the tags,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

The problem was that the tags are created in the Web "CD" so when I opened the item in the master "CM" the IDs are not found as shown in the picture.